# Uninstalling Systrack from CMD

Tags: cmd, uninstallation

So I'm trying to remotely uninstall the application SysTrack using:

```
 wmic product where "description='Systems Management Agent' " uninstall
```

but for some reason it can't find the product. Doing a

```
 product get name
```

from the wmic:root console, I don't see it listed. I'm wondering why the wmic can't get all the list of installed programs? It shows up on programs and features list, but now when I run that wmi command. I am a domain admin so the credentials should be a problem (the folder in the Program Files(x86) folder for SysTrack does have a lock on it though, but I can access)

Side note: I really wish there was a way to remotely just view that programs and features menu. Would be incredibly handy for the tasks I've been doing lately.

Comment: If you log in to the remote, it's being listed when you try to list all the programs with `wmic`? It also might be that you're not running it on the remote with elevated permissions. Give some more information about how you try to do it, how you connect, etc.

Comment: Well I can't even  do it locally so I don't think it's a remote problem but to remote in I'm doing:

    psexec.exe \remote-machine cmd.exe 

to get a remote command prompt

Comment: I really didn't understood what you're doing now. Still not working?

Answer (score 1):

try;

wmic product where "name like 'Systems Management Agent'" call uninstall /nointeractive

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in powershell ise.  It will take a list of hostnames from a text file and uninstall the application.  Edit the path for your local directory and text file name.

This script is 2 lines.  Everything before $app.Uninstall() is on one line and then $app.Uninstall() is the 2nd line.

$app = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName (Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\PowerShell\servers.txt") | Where-Object {$_.Name -match “Systems Management Agent”}
$app.Uninstall()